# Badge proposal: editing questions for new users

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-request

There's a [thing](https://twitter.com/robconery/status/974678531832610816) that happened recently with someone leaving Stack Exchange. Jon Skeet even has a [blog post](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2018/03/17/stack-overflow-culture/) about it. I was thinking about it, too.

I want to suggest a badge (Don't have a good name right now. Maybe "Hand-holder") to help address the problem. Provide a badge for users with more than 3000 rep (would have been eligible to vote to close) who edit a question scored -2 or less asked by a user with less than 50 rep, when that question later receives an upvote by someone else. Even better if the "new privileges" notification tells people they are now eligible for this badge.

The idea is to encourage people to fix bad questions to extent possible, rather than simply shouting them down right away. I don't think this will solve the problem, but it will send a better signal about the kind of behavior we expect from experienced users

Comment: What would this badge accomplish that the editor badge doesn't already cover?

Comment: @Makoto This is much more targeted. Also, editor only awards for the first edit. This could be re-awarded, to continually reinforce the behavior.

Comment: There is a disconnect here, Conery had 310 posts at SO before he decided to rage-quit.  Not a newbie by a long shot.  It is also very unclear how "check on comments and answers" was possibly getting him lectured and downvoted.  The more typical pattern with users like that is that they get bored.  Or got couple poorly received questions, they never forget that.

Comment: @HansPassant That's likely Rob's experience, yes. But when you generalize the problem, I think it's something more likely to involve new SO users (or at least new posters). I think putting more effort into editing instead of closing early on for new posters will help them see better patterns, and can reduce this problem over all. But if you've got 1000+ rep and still can't ask a question... well then maybe the community should just close it.

Comment: *Maybe "Hand-holder"* The Twitter thread you linked to has several people insisting that the Tumbleweed badge is maliciously sarcastic. I think a badge given to higher rep users for improving a post for a low rep user is going to be viewed as "~elite~ SO users patting themselves on the back".

Comment: @BSMP  I'm definitely not thrilled with the name, please suggest a better one. But the 2000 rep minimum is hardly elite level, and "patting on the back" is what gamification systems are all about.

Comment: Keep in mind that of all of the problems that a question can have that make it a bad question, it's fairly uncommon for them to be problems that can be fixed by an editor other than the author.  There are lots of ways for edits to make a question *better*, but generally they're either making a bad question less worse, but still bad, or making a good question even better, but when it was already acceptable from the start.

Comment: You need 3k rep to vote to close, not 2k, so if you want the badge to be for people who could have voted to close, you need the limit to be 3k.

Comment: @Servy hence the "later upvoted" part of the requirement. Hopefully the edit inspires some better/positive interactions with the OP so the question can be saved.

Comment: @Servy oops, editing to fix that now.  3000 is still hardly elite.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn The problem is that the later upvotes are so much more likely to be caused by something other than the edit though.  Either the OP added some information (either in comments or via a later edit) that helped the question actually become acceptable, or it was simply someone who disagreed with the earlier users' opinion on the quality of the post *regardless of the edit* (or only because the edit bumped the question), etc.  The odds that the reason for the later upvote is the edit just isn't super high.  Again, not zero, just not super high either.

Comment: I'm not saying that I *personally* think 2K or even 3K rep is high.

Comment: I would ask the question about the rep limit on this idea. If a low rep user can edit a post in order to save it like you are looking for here why can't they also be eligible for the badge? I don't see why someone with low rep can't help a new user improve a question.

Comment: @JoeW Trying to promote editing as an alternative to closing. Until 3000 rep, edits and comments are already your only options.

Comment: Users without the vote to close privilege can still flag a question for closure and while it does not have the same weight as a close vote it still is attempting to draw attention to and close the question. If you are really trying to provide an alternative to closing a question it should take into account flagging which can lead to closure as well.

Comment: Sure. That might be tough to account for properly, and it makes the description complex, but if we could make flags matter for this purpose I'd support it. Of course, we could also just stick our heads in the sand over this and not change anything. It's worked for the most part so far.

Comment: Just to sound a contrarian note, suppose a -5 "steaming pile of low effort" that's been edited a couple of times (probably trying to make it at least comprehensible) that has managed to avoid being closed. Now it gets upvoted by a charitable soul "for the feelz". That deserves a badge?

Comment: @Mark why not? We give bronze badges away just for filling out the profile. Maybe the edit saves a question. More likely not. But we reward the behavior for the editor. And now maybe the OP has a better experience and will stick around to ask better questions in the future.

Comment: It is one of the site's biggest problems, the steaming pile entries get re-activated over-and-over again and repeatedly makes it back onto users' Interesting page.  A good question that doesn't need editing disappears quickly.  Rewarding the crap with multiple edit badges seems counter-productive.

Comment: Yes, we award token participation badges to new users that at least make an attempt at engaging with the site's charter principles. Although, as @Servy pointed out, the link between a subsequent upvote and a prior edit seems pretty ephemeral. And, if the badge is to be awarded to _every_ editor of the question, this looks like it would incentivize "polishing turds" more than anything.

Comment: I'm having some difficulty following the path from "answer with score +29" -> "rage quit" -> "blog by Jon Skeet about answers and askers meeting each other in the middle" -> "users are being shouted down". I agree with every word of Jon's post, and I don't find this badge to be a completely unreasonable idea, but I am befuddled as to what they have to do with each other.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Rob Conery got a childish comment in one of his answers, which gave him the final bit of confirmation that SO regulars are largely jerks. Lots of people think we are all jerks. Sometimes that is due to a genuinely bad experience; sometimes that comes out of a refusal to even try to understand the principles of the site. All causes get conflated into a shapeless mass of negativity (often hallmarked by the word "toxic", which is appropriately shapeless), and Rob's tweets got sucked into it. Presumably Jon realises the conflation, but wants to meet the aggrieved folks in the middle.

Comment: _"All causes get conflated into a shapeless mass of negativity"_ This is an excellent observation; something I too have wondered how to address. That said, I saw the comment(s), and I'm sure they were aggravating. I sympathize _completely_ with frustration of getting comments from people who don't quite know what they're talking about, where you know exactly what you're talking about. I still don't see the line from ["people run their mouths in comments **on answers**"](https://xkcd.com/386/) to "people who ask questions are being 'shouted down'".

Comment: @JoshCaswell A connection might be drawn if one sees that comment as more than yet another instance of someone running their mouth on the Internet, but as a symptom of some issue with SO's culture. Under this interpretation, the shouting down would be another symptom. Alternatively -- and, I would add, more interestingly -- the resonance Rob's tweets found might have been taken as the symptom. This latter possibility leads me to wonder about the difference between a perceived cultural issue and a real cultural issue.

Answer (score 8):

To this point:

> The idea is to encourage people to fix bad questions to extent possible, rather than simply shouting them down right away.

There are two problems which exist with questions today which are being greatly simplified with this feature request.

- A question with problems to warrant downvotes may not be (and more times than we like to admit, *is* not) fixable by some John Doe editor.
- The mob exists and it gets it wrong sometimes.  There's no system in place to pick up the pieces after such a thing happens.

A badge to edit content isn't going to help address the fact that the mob has already been here and ransacked the place, nor is it going to make the frustration go anywhere, either.  Worse, it assumes that The Problem™ is something that anyone looking at a question can objectively identify, isolate, and fix without any further input from the OP.

Most questions I see that have problems usually follow the pattern of, "Can you do this for me?"  No amount of editing effort I put into a question will ***ever*** be able to fix that.  The questions that I do see which are rough copy edits but still serviceable questions are more the ones I spend my time and energy on, but those are ***incredibly*** rare.  I've seen maybe a hundred in the six years I've been here.

---

A while back when Stack Exchange was looking for micro-privileges, [I had floated the idea of spending your own rep to help a question get forgiven](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259077/175248).  I'm not sure what status that project is in right now but I'd hope it gets revisited for the simple use case you describe:  we want to encourage users to improve their questions and not feel like this place is too overly oppressive.