# Making downvotes more useful

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, voting

Some problems:

- Large numbers of downvotes scare people away

  - This contributes to Stack Overflow’s reputation of being an unfriendly place
- Upvotes are made to “counterbalance” downvotes (this happens because of the previous) instead of because a question or answer is good

  - Users feel like their votes don’t matter
- A single upvote cancels out either 2.5 or 5 downvotes and can result in net positive reputation for very bad posts (this tends to happen because of the previous)

  - People are incentivized to keep wrong answers around!

My suggestion for a solution to these problems is to, for negative-scored questions and answers, display −1 as the score and apply −5 to reputation¹. In other words:

- continue displaying −1 as the score for any post scored lower than −1
- cap rep loss from any post at −5¹
- make downvotes worth the same as upvotes for negative-scored posts

Let’s fix the C/C++² undefined behaviour dogpiles! The net wins for undetected sockpuppets on −4-scored questions! The apparent³ incentive to delete and re-ask downvoted questions instead of fixing them! The general frustration and feeling of unwelcomeness of new users, even if they totally deserve it for not reading the FAQ⁴! Let’s free people of the guilt of voting on questions that need improvement lest too many share the opinion, and even things out for popular tags.

---

<sub>¹ or something – [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) is solicited</sub>
<sub>² heh heh</sub>
<sub>³ it results in a question ban, but they don’t know that and will do it anyway</sub>
<sub>⁴ just so we’re clear: this is not true</sub>

Comment: The solution is not about points/votes. The real solution is making people read how to ask a good question and not do the typical "Do my homework for me because I am lazy to put in the effort." I remember having to crack open a book to find an answer. There was no google/stackoverflow. People are just so used to getting thinks quickly that they do not put the time and effort into things. I just wish half the people would spend an extra 60 seconds writing full sentences and using the shift key to uppercase letters. Heck half the time if they search their title on Google, it is the first result

Comment: @epascarello: I think this change incentivizes people to fix up their bad questions. Getting people to ask good questions from the start is also a nice goal, but it doesn’t need to be to the exclusion of all other improvement.

Comment: The ~10 years I been on this site, people do not change their bad questions. They complain when we ask them nicely to update it with info. People just want answers and some times people spend more time complaining about us not helping them than it would have taken to add the code to the question. I think I spend more time asking people to give us the error message in JavaScript questions than I do answering them.

Comment: _"make downvotes worth the same as upvotes for negative-scored posts"_ What does this mean? Doesn't seem to follow from the rest.

Comment: @epascarello: “People don’t change their bad questions”… except for some people. Again, I think this will improve that proportion. It also has benefits for bad questions that remain bad, i.e. not attracting pity votes.

Comment: And the other issue with bad questions is rep hungry people will answer them before they can be improved. Saw that 4 times today with "do my homework" questions.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: It means any post with a negative score will always have net −2 rep. For example, in the current system, a question with 10 downvotes and 5 upvotes will have a score of −5 and give +5 rep (or +25 if the downvotes were given while the user had 1 rep and the upvotes all came after the downvotes); under this proposal, it will be −2 rep.

Comment: @epascarello: That kind of thing is also partially addressed here, preventing downvoted answers from being large net positives. (If an answer to a bad question gets 4 downvotes for being a rep grab, 1 upvote currently makes it positive. I’m proposing to make a +1/−2 answer give −2 rep.)

Comment: I see, the value of both kinds of votes changes. I read is as using the _current_ value of upvotes. Might be better expressed as "upvotes have no effect until they equal the number of downvotes", or something like that.

Comment: And than you have the people that up-vote horrible questions because they are getting their daily point quota of imaginary points. Those people screw up any balances you try to put in place. We all see it. A question is asked and 30 seconds later, it has 2 up-votes and it will be closed within minutes.

Comment: Did you mean up-cap or down-cap? (you get at most -2 or you get at least -2?)

Comment: @user202729: You lose at most 2 rep from any post. (And never gain rep from votes on a post unless it has a positive score.)

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269461/why-do-people-take-downvotes-so-personally). [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311406/is-using-an-up-vote-to-balance-out-a-down-vote-wrong).

Comment: @epascarello: I don’t see that, and I don’t see what that has to do with this suggestion either.

Comment: About (3)... yes, the reputation system is somewhat broken there, but they would get question-banned anyway, so no problem.

Comment: @user202729: Only if it’s not one of several users with 10k+ rep thanks to multiple thousand mostly low-quality questions.

Comment: Ok, giving net negative reputation for negatively scored posts can be good. Because reputation --> privileges. But why capping them at -2 (why not (2×score)?) And what is the "display score as -1" used for?

Comment: @user202729: The loss capping and hiding of negative scores stop people from being put off the site by all the downvotes if a bad question happens to attract a lot of attention, and stop people from upvoting only to balance that score accordingly.

Comment: I like the part about not earning rep from bad posts. With regards to people voting to counterbalance, is there any data to show how widespread that is?

Comment: Is the "capped -1" shown to everyone, or only to the OP? If it's to everyone, then I think they will be confused when their vote doesn't change the score (unless for those 1k+ rep users who can see the voting breakdown)

Comment: @AndrewT.: To everyone. People would get used to it. Could show − or something instead of −1.

Comment: @Ry︁ How would new users learn what *really*  bad questions look like when every   downvoted question look the same (in votes)?

Comment: Meh - the whole premise was wrong in the first place.  If a user is put off by a Q&A site by negative votes on bad questions, they are not professional/enthusiast programmers.  Now we are stuck forever with 'i=i++', NPE and 'Homework Sunday' :(

Comment: I did not downvote this post.  At least is suggests something that does not require more effort from the skilled and experienced developers who try to give good answers to good questions, unlike the usual 'explain downvotes' and 'appeal procedure' super-dupes that just want someone else to waste volunteer time on bad questions:(

Comment: @ModusTollens: I’m not sure that new users learn that way to begin with? The number of downvotes a question gets doesn’t always reflect whether it’s *really* bad – just whether it’s at the right intersection of bad and visible enough to get a lot of downvotes – and the ones that are really bad get deleted quickly, not left up to serve as examples.

Comment: @Ry︁ Well I did. Lurk and learn. Old school :D

Comment: I disagree with this feature request mainly because of the proposed display of "-1" for all downvoted posts. There _are_ strong quality differences between downvoted posts, and I'd like to see that expressed. It puts a certain pressure on posters to see a large negative value next to their post. It also helps answering questions like "why am I question banned" on meta. Seeing the actual score of a post is important imho.

Comment: @ModusTollens stop being reasonable.  How can I have a good rant when everyone around is being reasonable?  It's not fair!

Comment: "more useful [(usefulness may vary)]?"

Comment: I keep on hearing people say "Stack Overflow has a bad reputation of being unfriendly," yet whenever I talk to a fellow developer in real life, Stack Overflow for them is a great repository to find answers to all sorts of programming questions. The only people I really see calling it unfriendly are people who come here expecting to do a code dump of something that isn't working hoping that SO will debug and fix it for them or who drop a list of requirements expecting SO to provide a coded solution. And those people feel it's unfriendly because they didn't get what they want.

Comment: @DavyM Stack Overflow is the only place on the network where I've received offensive comments directed at me (also, I've never used this site as my personal code dumping ground—not that it should matter: it's "Be Nice", not "Be Nice IFF The User Follows All The Rules"). Not that this has anything to do with downvotes...

Comment: @DavyM I regularly give talks and mentor at a bootcamp style code school. When they hear about my stack overflow participation, they ask questions about it. I can attest that these folks are routinely scared of participating in stack overflow because of how new people are treated. These are not freeloaders. These are people who have left other careers because of their passion for software development. They're highly intelligent, but very inexperienced, inexperienced enough that it is difficult for them to know even with the guidelines whether they've asked a good enough question.

Comment: @Laurel I'm speaking specifically of the people who feel that Stack Overflow is unfriendly because it doesn't provide them with the work being done for them, and when that doesn't happen just like they want, they get upset. People being rude is a completely different point and is entirely unacceptable, though if it makes you feel better, I've had someone be rude to me on the Mathematics stack exchange and I've definitely seen a lot of rude comments on the Interpersonal Skills stack exchange, although those get deleted pretty quickly by moderators, so SO isn't alone in having a few rude people.

Comment: At some point, we have to adapt to new users, yes.  But at the same time, users have to adapt to us.  It's a two way street.  I feel this moves the mark too much in new users' favor, and away from the very people who the site needs to survive; the high rep users who actually care about quality.  What sort of message are you sending when you weight new user retention over established users?

Comment: @fbueckert: How do established users get hurt by this? Their votes count more, rep-wise, in the cases where it matters, and established users worried about downvoting too much won’t have to. Meanwhile new users start adapting instead of leaving, thanks to more helpful comments now that downvoted questions aren’t seen as lost causes. Maybe.

Comment: I feel it's a pap for new users, so they don't feel so bad, when that's not at all what downvotes are for.  They're *meant* to show the subjective quality of a post for future readers, and you're removing that in the name of trying to keep people who...honestly, aren't really worth keeping.  Why should we want to keep people who make no effort to learn?  Whereas signalling to future readers that this post is strongly negative sends a message to take it with a large grain of salt.

Comment: @fbueckert: Correct, downvotes are not for making people feel bad. They do, though, hence this fix attempt. −1 is enough to indicate quality much of the time, and real scores can be displayed when helpful (e.g. review queues or when requested by someone with the privilege).

Comment: And it's a lifelong problem; no matter where you go, people don't like criticism.  That doesn't mean you withold it.

Comment: I'll say it again.. if someone feels bad about negative imaginary internet points, they should not be trying to develop software - they don't have the required mental strength to fight with pages of error messages and difficult bugs.  They should pick another profession/course/hobby because the tools we use don't care a PHP about any snowflake's feelings.

Comment: @DavyM I feel StackOverflow is unfriendly because often people are unkind and impatient - not to me but to others. The attitude appears to be "ask your first question perfectly or get downvoted". Downvotes without explanation aren't helpful: "I think you did something wrong but it's on you to figure out what that is".  There are better ways of helping new users adapt to the site then anonymous downvotes.  Many of the comments to this question show the attitudes which I feel are behind much of the toxicity on SO...but I'll leave it to you to figure out which comments :)

Comment: I feel StackOverflow is unfriendly because often people are unkind and impatient -both to me and to others. The attitude appears to be "PHP the rules and post whatever question yo uwnat anyway". It is perceived by some OP's that downvotes without explanation aren't helpful, but if asked for for $100 up-front to contract skilled and experienced developers to provide in-depth voting details, they would balk at the very thought of not getting the rules explained for free.

Comment: For free, "I think you did something wrong but it's on you to figure out what that is" is all that volunteers care to donate.  There have been no better ways suggested of helping new users adapt to the site then anonymous downvotes. Many of the comments to this question show the attitudes which I feel are behind much of the 'I want other people to do my research, read the rules/policy and tell me what they think I did wrong and, if I don't like what I hear, I'll flag them as unhlelpful, rude and/or abusive'  attitude on SO...but I'll leave it to you to figure out which comments

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we make it more obvious to new users that downvotes on the main site are not insults and in fact can help them help themselves?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366889/can-we-make-it-more-obvious-to-new-users-that-downvotes-on-the-main-site-are-not)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My instinctive suspicion about this suggestion is that even if multiple downvotes were hidden, most people who feel unwelcome because of downvoting now would still feel unwelcome, only for *other* reasons: because extra effort is asked of them, or because their posts get criticised, or because their questions are closed, or because they get quetsion banned, and so forth. Questions like "Is Stack Overflow unwelcoming?" seem to induce a confusing mix of perception and reality ([cf. this recent ruckus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364815/badge-proposal-editing-questions-for-new-users?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment566819_364815)), and my gut feeling is that a change like this one would drag us a little further into that.

Now, if I suspend the aforementioned feeling (say, by telling myself "It's okay, this might make at least *some* people happier, and perhaps the site would run more smoothly as a consequence"), I end up with a view rather similar to [the one held by Makoto](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/365552/2751851): this wouldn't be an unreasonable PR move, but it would bring in a lot of practical complications. I will mention a few additional ones:

- If no one sees the real negative scores below -1, there is a risk that very few people will be aware that further negative votes count and are important for several moderation mechanisms. (It is important to keep in mind that many -- and probably most -- regular contributors with high reputation aren't Meta regulars.) That might be mitigated by showing real negative scores to 1k+ users (i.e. the ones currently able to see the score breakdown).
- I'm not entirely convinced this change would deliver us from counterbalancing upvotes. My home tag is [haskell], [one of the "nicest" language tags you'll find](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/337152/2751851), one in which dogpiles are relatively rare -- and yet I regularly see incomprehensible upvotes being cast on poor questions with -1 score.
- Would "mak[ing] downvotes worth the same as upvotes for negative-scored posts" mean that, given a 0 score question, a downvote followed by an upvote would lead to a different reputation change than an upvote followed by a downvote? That would feel rather arbitrary. (Or is the idea that reputation for a post would be recalculated every time it crossed the 0 score boundary?)

Answer (score 19):

I kind of miss the ulterior motive of your request. It would appear to be a reincarnation of the Summer of Love, just to retain as many users as possible, despite their actions and their effect on the community.

I have a counter-proposal: shadowban people who consistently upvote bad questions, meaning their votes would appear to be registered for them - but not for anyone else.

Seriously, Stack Overflow has no lack of influx of questions nor users. If anything, it's chasing away knowledgeable users by the amount of crap that gets posted and not closed, let alone downvoted or deleted.

Asking a question is hard, asking a good question even harder. This site definitely shouldn't turn into a "noob-friendly" zone where all we care about are feewings, because that creates one environment and one environment only: one of the blind leading the blind.

If -1 would be the new low, then why would anyone still vote to score a really bad post even lower?

Comment: ...and then, as the 'knowledgeable' skilled/experienced developers give up, there are fewer user-moderators to downvote and close the crap, so it stays around longer, and gets answered, and the answers get upvoted, and another generation of skilled users thinks: 'why am I wasting my free time on the same old rubbish day-after-day'....... and so life goes on, (as does death).

Comment: @MartinJames at least all those posters of crap feel welcome!

Comment: "I have a counter-proposal: shadowban people who consistently upvote bad questions" There are a number of big problems here.  First, many of these questions end up with positive scores, not negative scores, because the users looking to feed the help vampires outnumber the users interested in quality content in many tags or topics, or more hit a given question, etc.  The whole problem here is that votes are how we identify what questions are good/bad, and the problematic behavior here is people not using those votes well, so we don't have an accurate view of what posts are actually bad.

Comment: *“If -1 would be the new low, then why would anyone still vote to score a really bad post even lower?”* To put forward their opinion on a question, like always, and to alter the real score to affect automated processes/review, where people can see it/etc.. The purpose of voting isn’t to try to reach low number records. (And personally, I don’t vote on bad posts if they’re already low enough, but would if it didn’t change the count displayed to the owner.)

Comment: @Ry︁ "and to alter the real score to affect automated processes/review, where people can see it/etc.." -- With further negative votes having little in the way of immediately visible effect, I wouldn't be surprised if, outside of the circle of Meta regulars, most users ended up unaware of "real scores" being a thing. One way of mitigating that might be showing the real scores to all 1k+ users (i.e. those who would be able to see the voting breakdown anyway).

Answer (score -4):

Honestly I like what this approach is *attempting* to accomplish.

- We eliminate the noise of "Stack Overflow is mean" by basically giving the *perception* of us not being all that mean.
- We eliminate the dogpile effect of users saying, "Oh, a poorly scored question.  I too will add my downvote."
- We eliminate cases in which users will spontaneously upvote a question *just because* it was downvoted and they disagree with the downvote, not because the question was any good or didn't deserve the downvote, but because they disagreed with the vote *itself*.

Tl;dr:  **we make moderation more efficient and effective by lying about moderation.**

A couple of issues:

- This doesn't cleanly solve the dogpile problem.  Instead of a user seeing a question scored at -4, they'll see it at -1 and still want to downvote it.
- You didn't say anything about retroactively scoring questions, or the ramifications of  that if we *did*.  We can't realistically have two reputation types since that'd make for a colossal headache.
- How is "success" measured or identified?  More people sticking around? More downvotes?  More closed questions?

On that point of "more people sticking around", I think the issue being underscored here is that we have fewer *experts* sticking around, whereas we get every single CompSci 101 student that we could support (and then some).  How would this proposal actually address this point?

I like what you're getting at.  I don't think it gets at it.

Comment: As is brought up in comments, yes, not telling people when they do bad things does make them feel better, because it feels bad to be told that you did bad things, but then *those people don't realize they were doing something bad*, and so are going to make no attempt to improve their problematic behavior, or even realize they're expected to.

Comment: Yes, but @Servy we both know how we define "bad" things on Stack Overflow is a moving target at *best*.  There is no universally and consistently applied standard for when questions are up or downvoted, and some questionable questions slip through the cracks. So being told you're bad for reasons unknown *does* suck.  However, I still agree with you here in principle; we don't solve anything if we just flat-out *lie* about the moderation we're doing here.

Comment: There's *lots* of information in the help center, in the FAQ's, on meta, and in tutorials on the internet at large about how to ask a good question (on SO and in general).  While, yes, it is hard to ask questions, I don't think it's a result of a lack of information on how to ask good questions, it's just that it takes a fair bit of time and effort to actually do it, which people aren't often willing to put in.  Yes, there will be borderline cases where it's not clear to a user if, or why, their question is problematic, but for the *vast* majority of questions, that's not the case.

Comment: Oh, and in my experiences a *very* large portion of bad questions attract comments with additional information on how the question is problematic and could be improved.  There's also close reasons that provide more specific guidance on what's problematic about a question.

Comment: @Servy:  [In my personal experience I'll have to disagree.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533816/1079354)  No one told me *why* that question was bad.  It's tough in my mind to see what one or two things could be improved in that question to make it *less* bad.  So clearly I did a bad thing.  I have studied and perused all of the guidance and documentation and I felt strongly that this question was suitable and on-topic.  Yet...here it lies, below the watermark.  I see where you're coming from that *typically* questions get that kind of treatment, but not all questions get that lucky.

Comment: That's...one question.  I didn't say all quesitons get comments, just lots of them.  And as I said before, there will be borderline questions that aren't easy to diagnose why they're problematic, but *most* questions will find clear guidance on how to improve via the sources I've mentioned.  It's certainly not worth refusing to tell *all* people that their posts are problematic just because a small minority of post authors don't have the tools to figure out how to fix their questions, even though the rest can.

Comment: *“We eliminate the noise of "Stack Overflow is mean" by basically giving the perception of us not being all that mean.”* Making sure we’re on the same page: that perception would reflect reality. Downvotes aren’t mean, but people think they are. (I strategically avoid downvoting for this reason and proposed this change in part to do it freely.) Re: dogpiles: these are partially accurate votes, so the effect continuing to exist shouldn’t do much harm. Re: success: by fewer angry comments and account self-deletions, more self-improved questions, no acceleration of the general decline in quality.