# Can we make the voting tooltip reasons more-visible?

Tags: feature-request, downvotes, voting, downvote-reason

Often times we have users who come in here asking to "require commenting to downvote" at-least in part because they don't understand what a downvote means.

That often leads to someone informing them that the assumed reason is someone felt that:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

For a new and inexperienced user especially though, this information is not especially easy to find. It's tucked away behind a tooltip (which are especially hidden on mobile devices).

Is there any way that this information could be made more-visible to users?

Comment: Dunno what this would accomplish. When the tooltip text is pointed out to people who ask for requiring comments, it never seems to satisfy them.

Comment: As a tooltip, it is *not visible at all* until someone hovers over it – and you have to *know* that you can hover there. That is the reason behind Alexander's question. So, the message could be made to automatically appear when a certain threshold gets reached – after *x* downvotes, or when the net vote count is below *y*, or when it gathered *z* close votes, for example.

Comment: Also, note that the tooltip is different for answers.

Comment: [Display a message to a user the first time they receive a downvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373477/display-a-message-to-a-user-the-first-time-they-receive-a-downvote)

Answer (score 2):

Being downvoted has too many negative connotations associated with it for any literature to clarify or disambiguate.  At best, you're looking at a circumstance in which an end user reads the literature and accepts that their question or answer *may* have been poor.

But you're likely not going to get that in a social media culture which prioritizes likes and upvotes and any form of positive feedback, which results in a backlash if anything is received negatively.  (You'll see this manifest with a demand for justification, typically.)

So what do we do?  [This suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365526/1079354) in which one solution would be to just show -1 for a post which is *heavily* downvoted to lessen the impact.  Some valid points are brought up in there in which those who want to feel insulted *will* feel insulted, but the overall thrust ain't too bad...

Comment: There are some suggetions which suggests showing a "!" too, which tooltip explaining the post needs improvement, which IIRC receives better feedback than the "-1" suggestion.